# Remove doc_title date/time stamp

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-shared-drive

I want to remove the date and time stamp on doc_title value in a simpler way. The stamp appears either before or after the name part in the doc_title.

title values

FileName1 (2018-03-07 at 09:00 GMT-8),
(2018-03-05 at 06:44 GMT-8) FileName2,
(2018-03-05 at 12:15 GMT-8) FileName3,
(2018-03-01 at 07:17 GMT-8) FileName4,
FileName5 (2018-03-05 at 12:15 GMT-8)

I tried using the logical OR to catch if it's at the end or at the beginning. But it is catching only the first condition.

```
doc_title = title.split((" \\(")||("\\) "));
```

Also tried
    doc_title = title.split((" (") || (") "));

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to retrieve `FileName1, FileName2, FileName3, FileName4, FileName5` from `FileName1 (2018-03-07 at 09:00 GMT-8), (2018-03-05 at 06:44 GMT-8) FileName2, (2018-03-05 at 12:15 GMT-8) FileName3, (2018-03-01 at 07:17 GMT-8) FileName4, FileName5 (2018-03-05 at 12:15 GMT-8)`. If my understanding is correct, how about this? I think that there are several answers for your situation, so please think of this as one of them.

```
doc_title = title.replace(/\(\w.+?\)/, "").trim();
```

#### Sample snippet :

```js
var titles = ["FileName1 (2018-03-07 at 09:00 GMT-8)", "(2018-03-05 at 06:44 GMT-8) FileName2", "(2018-03-05 at 12:15 GMT-8) FileName3", "(2018-03-01 at 07:17 GMT-8) FileName4", "FileName5 (2018-03-05 at 12:15 GMT-8)"];
for (var i in titles) {
  var doc_title = titles[i].replace(/\(\w.+?\)/, "").trim();
  console.log(doc_title)
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, please tell me. I would like to modify it.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike, it worked, how is it (/\(\w.+?\)/, "") splitting this?

Comment: @Shaheryar Rajper I used the regex for your situation. ``\(\w.+?\)`` means the enclosed values by the parentheses. For example, for the case of ``FileName1 (2018-03-07 at 09:00 GMT-8)`` and ``(2018-03-05 at 06:44 GMT-8) FileName2``, those are ``(2018-03-07 at 09:00 GMT-8)`` and ``(2018-03-05 at 06:44 GMT-8)``. Using ``replace(/\(\w.+?\)/, "")``, ``(2018-03-07 at 09:00 GMT-8)`` and ``(2018-03-05 at 06:44 GMT-8)`` are replaced by ``""``. So the remained values are ``FileName1 `` and ``FileName2``. And then, I used ``trim()`` to remove the spaces. Is my understanding for your comment correct?

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike, how can i also remove the space with the same trim before or after the filename?

Comment: @Shaheryar Rajper Yes. You can remove the space using ``trim()``. In my answer, ``trim()`` has already been used.